# Can't load data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite, pdo

Here is my problem. I'm setting up a calendar and I am having trouble switching from the sqlite database to my mysql database.

The problem is that DayPilot isn't loading the events when they are passed from mysql. Any help is grately appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?php

//$db_exists = file_exists("daypilot1.sqlite");
//$db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite'); This works

// i tried these two ways. both of them did not work.

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=his", "root", "123"); 


/* $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123";


try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=his", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  */

if (!$db) {
    //create the database
    $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
                        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                        name TEXT, 
                        start DATETIME, 
                        end DATETIME,
                        resource VARCHAR(30))");

    $messages = array(
                    array('name' => 'Event 1',
                        'start' => '2013-05-09T00:00:00',
                        'end' => '2013-05-09T10:00:00',
                        'resource' => 'B')
                );

    $insert = "INSERT INTO events (name, start, end, resource) VALUES (:name, :start, :end, :resource)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($insert);

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
    $stmt->bindParam(':resource', $resource);

    foreach ($messages as $m) {
      $name = $m['name'];
      $start = $m['start'];
      $end = $m['end'];
      $resource = $m['resource'];
      $stmt->execute();
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php

//$db_exists = file_exists("daypilot1.sqlite");
//$db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite'); This works

// i tried these two ways. both of them did not work.

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=his", "root", "123"); 


/* $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123";


try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=his", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  */

if (!$db) {
    //create the database
    $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
                        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                        name TEXT, 
                        start DATETIME, 
                        end DATETIME,
                        resource VARCHAR(30))");

    $messages = array(
                    array('name' => 'Event 1',
                        'start' => '2013-05-09T00:00:00',
                        'end' => '2013-05-09T10:00:00',
                        'resource' => 'B')
                );

    $insert = "INSERT INTO events (name, start, end, resource) VALUES (:name, :start, :end, :resource)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($insert);


    foreach ($messages as $m) {
      $name = $m['name'];
      $start = $m['start'];
      $end = $m['end'];
      $resource = $m['resource'];
    }

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
    $stmt->bindParam(':resource', $resource);
    $stmt->execute();

}

?>
```

I have not tested it but hopes it will solve your problem.

Comment: what is the change in this code? this is the original code

Comment: Anayway thaks for your response

Comment: @user2781812 `$stmt->execute();` is out from loop and `$stmt->bindParam` is after loop.